# Is JAVA RMI still being used anywhere?

Tags: java, web-services, rmi

I was reading about the Proxy Design Pattern from BOOK - [Head First Design Patterns](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/head-first-design/0596007124/ch11.html). In there they were talking about using RMI to make proxy communicate with Remote Object.

Is it still being used even after wide adoption of WebServices?

Answer (score 1):

RMI is getting a lot less use these days. As you point out various other kinds of client/server communication are widely adopted. However, even if you wanted to use a binary protocol to send objects, RMI is based on Java serialization which is not as efficient as something like Kryo. I recently wrote code that communicated between client and server using a serialization protocol, but I used Kryo and sockets to do the job and not RMI.